# How to Click 'OK' or 'CANCEL' on a JS popup (authentication) within Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, authentication, selenium-ide

I have looked this over and over and it seems that the other related threads really didn't solve any of the questions?!

First of all, please do NOT say how to do this in Selenium WD - we understand this method and it is not applicable for our UAT testing.  The tool is Selenium IDE and we just have to click either "OK" or "CANCEL"

Pre-condition:
Firefox is setup to remember usernames/passwords and you can see this when the confirmation box is presented to the user as:

- Title of Window : Authentication required
- Content of Window : {{Site}} is requesting your username and password
- Username/Password : Filled out with the correct credentials

We are just trying to click the OK button.  You can't inspect the element because it is JS, and we just want to know what is the easiest way of clicking the "OK" or "CANCEL" buttons on this dialog.

I have tried StoreAlert, StoreConfirmation, ChooseOKOnNextConfirmation and ChooseCancelOnNextConfirmation and none of which seem to work.

If you respond, please be specific with "Command", "Target" and "Value" fields.

Comment: I can see the JS dialog details when I use UI Spy or (Microsoft) Inspect.exe, but I still can't access it within Selenium IDE.  Seems very difficult to find a solution for something that doesn't seem that complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now successful in doing this 2 different ways using AutoIt.  I was not able to consume and handle the popup using just selenium ide.  SeleniumHQ.org has examples on how to handle prompts, alerts and dialogs but the "Authentication Required" popup is not in scope.

Method #1:  AutoIt sending username, password and clicking the 'ok' button

- Execute the AutoIt script that sends the user name, password and clicks the 'ok' button (this script should be looping waiting for the popup in next step)
- **Execute the Selenium IDE script that triggers the site you're testing to display the "Authentication Required" popup.  This might just be hitting the site.**
- Put the Selenium IDE script into a sleep (sleep command)
- AutoIt script takes over (sees the prompt) and sends the user name, password and clicks the 'ok' button.  AutoIt script terminates
- Selenium IDE script comes out of sleep and continues the test of the test case

Method #2

- Execute the AutoIt script that clicks the 'ok' button (this script should be looping waiting for the popup in next step)
- **Execute the Selenium IDE script that hits the site but has the user:pass in the URL of the site.**
- Put the Selenium IDE script into a sleep (sleep command)
- AutoIt script takes over (sees the prompt) and sends and clicks the 'ok' button.  AutoIt script terminates
- Selenium IDE script comes out of sleep and continues the test of the test case

Summary:  Method#1 uses the AutoIt script to enter the user, pass and click the 'ok' button.  Method#2 used the AutoIt script just to click the 'ok' button because when you hit the site with the user:pass in the URL, a different confirmation popup is displayed with just 'ok' or 'cancel'.